# ERROR: dP15zlyra3c: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

Tags: python-3.x

I found the code below at [Youtube download using Youtube-dl embedded with Python - 2020](https://www.bogotobogo.com/VideoStreaming/YouTube/youtube-dl-embedding.php)

After I ran `pip3 list` I saw `youtube-dl 2020.3.24` in the list.

However, when I run...

```
# ydl1.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP15zlyra3c'])
```

I see the following error...

```
[youtube] dP15zlyra3c: Downloading webpage
ERROR: dP15zlyra3c: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1788, in _real_extract
    raise ExtractorError(
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: dP15zlyra3c: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ydl1.py", line 7, in <module>
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP15zlyra3c'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2018, in download
    res = self.extract_info(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: dP15zlyra3c: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
y@y-peppy:~/.config/autokey$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating youtube-dl. Depending on the way you installed it, here are the commands:(in windows)

1-youtube-dl --update (self-update)

2-pip install -U youtube-dl (via python)

3-choco upgrade youtube-dl (Windows + Chocolatey)

and a cookies.txt file can be created with the "`cookies.txt`" extension.
Do this while being logged in to YouTube.
for example :

For Firefox:
[this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-txt/)

For Chrome:[this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg)

Then run youtube-dl like this:

`youtube-dl.exe --cookies C:\Users\tezJR\Downloads\cookies-txt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$VIDEO-ID`

adjust that command to where your cookies.txt file is actually located and replace $VIDEO-ID with the ID of your restricted video

Comment: Thank you! I'm on Linux therefore I updated youtube-dl with: pip3 install -U youtube-dl. Now it works properly for me!

Comment: I would like to hover over a YouTube video with my mouse and then run a Python script which would paste the URL of the video my mouse was hovering over into the Python script I indicated in my initial question. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: For ubuntu users: `sudo apt purge youtube-dl`  and then `sudo pip3 install youtube-dl` or you use this if you get error by updating youtube-dl by downloading a .deb from `https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/youtube-dl/download`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that @Salio.